# Toshiba recovery disc doesn't give me all partition options

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, operating-systems

I'm trying to install Windows XP on a new machine, by way of the original Toshiba XP recovery disc. (I can use a recovery disc on not-the-original machine can't I?)

When I boot up with the disc in, I get to a point when it asks me how I want to install. I select the 'existing partition' option. It then gives me a dialog saying it will install into the SYSTEM partition, which is tiny.

Obviously I don't want to overwrite SYSTEM, so how can I install XP on one of my empty partitions (already created)?

I know it's possible to install the OS from the CD on a separate machine (just tried in a virtual one). Maybe I can move the partitions around if it just selects the first one?

Comment: Custom Recovery discs provided by manufacturers are only intended to be used on the machine they are sold with and most are not configurable as to what partition to install on, any other use is a violation of the eula with Microsoft.

Comment: @Moab Don't know about the US, but German courts allow resale of OEM licenses. AFAICT this case is similar (nobody cares about EULA rules that don't comply with the law), making this a legitimate technical problem.

Comment: Customized recovery discs do not use a single user OEM licence, they use a embedded OEM VLK tied to the manufacturer of the PC. So yes it is a violation. I am not taking about a normal OS install disc which few pc manufacturers provide anymore.

Comment: I've just found out (in the VM) that I can't run the OS anyway. online install fails, and I'm presuming that's because I'm using a different machine than the disk was designed for.

Comment: @ACarter yes most PC manufacturers tie the recovery discs to the original hardware by checking the bios tattoo information during recovery.

Comment: Wonder if I can buy a 32bit XP cheaply anywhere..... ;)

Comment: Might be hard to find a legal key that has not been activated yet. eBay comes to mind. Install media can be found easily, its the key that you need.

Comment: (Just while we're on the topic) Where can you find the install media? I haven't found any in my research.

Comment: @ACarter I use Dell XP install media, you just have to [change the product key](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328874) once you are at the desktop, there are millions of Dell XP cds out there.

Comment: The ironic thing is that it will cost me more to buy 32bit Win7 or XP than it cost me to buy Win8!